# Efficient way of finding the first occurrance of a number in a 2D scipy array?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to find the occurance of certain number in a 2D scipy array. The returned value should be the indices of first and second slice like (x,y).

What could be an absolutely efficient way of doing it?

Thanks a lot